Erasing data from a server/ssd
Imagine the following use case: I have confidential data saved on storage and want to delete it so I can forward the storage to another person, who will probably try everything the market offers to get the data. What do I do?
My idea is to encrypt the data with vera crypt + serpent first, then xor every register with each other to make the contents zeros. Would that be enough?

Don't make up your own scheme. Secure data erasure is a common problem and it has solutions. It's generally enough to use a secure erase program for SSDs. If you don't trust any program to performs this data erasure then you have to physically destroy the disk, which can be easily done at home. Other people have asked the same question too, see here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5662/is-it-enough-to-only-wipe-a-flash-drive-once and also here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225451/how-to-physically-destroy-an-ssd-at-home

physical destruction cannot be done, as the hardware has to be recycled due to the norms. the idea goes beyond common secure erase programs available on the market. my question is, what are the open challenges and possible solutions to the problem?

Please explain clearly why the drive cannot be physically destroyed.

Your data is not confidential once you upload your data unencrypted on the cloud. This was your mistake and you want to cover your trails. Agencies already got it, and probably the provider already had snapshots around.

As highlighted below several times, you can't "then xor every register with each other to make the contents zeros" with any confidence.

In your specific use case there is (almost) nothing you can do.
Your problem is that it is impossible to verify that data sanitisation worked on an SSD.
Let me quote NIST Special Publication 800-88, Guidelines for Media Sanitization:-

The application of Destructive techniques may be the only option when the media fails and other
Clear or Purge techniques cannot be effectively applied to the media, or when the verification of
Clear or Purge methods fails (for known or unknown reasons).

which you can't for reasons described in that document.  Also I recall that malware has been found in the firmware of branded mass produced hard discs. That can impede erasure. So physical destruction is the only reliable method and hence recommended for classified/secret data.
Almost: Quoting from National Cyber Security Center: Secure sanitisation of storage media:-

It is important to use encryption so that the problem of partial erasure does not incur exorbitant cost or unacceptable risks at end-of-life. Encryption is also important when considering re-use across your estates, since removing the key will render the content of the SSD unreadable (assuming contemporary industry-standard encryption is used), thus allowing for re-use in different (or less secure) environments.

But only if you believe that the encryption works/ is implemented correctly or cannot be bypassed.  And the identical problem remains in that you cannot verify this (comes back to the NIST quote).
So burn it and only then give away the ashes to your friend.

the problem is, the SSD has to be recycled and cannot be burned. The idea of encrypting is ok, since even if you get the data, its encrypted. How should a standardised, well implemented encryption be bypassed/reversed, without knowing the key?

The problem here is that there have been instances where SECURE ERASE (for SATA SSD's) or SANITIZE commands have not been correctly implemented. I very much which this hasn't been the case, but without any method of confirming that it is hard to recommend such methods for really sensitive data that takes in direct access to the flash memory & controller chip. It is one reason why I kept buying Intel, because regardless of market position, those drives tend to be well tested. Unfortunately that's not a valuable position for consumer level SSD's.

@MaartenBodewes lets talk about corporate level of security. is there no way to encrypt the data on your own, even when the built-in functions of the drives are bad? Dont you have access to that? Also, cant you just take all the data and encrypt it on your own (e.g. with serpent) and just leave it on the drive?

Yes, full disk encryption can of course work, usually at the expense of compute power, drive speeds and less hardware protection of the keys. If you use the hardware encryption features of drives then you're basically back at square one. Note that there may also be some disadvantages to drive encryption schemes. Beware that you generally don't have logical access to all the flash storage on the drive due to write leveling (drives have more memory than they advertise to the system).

For normal functionality, especially with enterprise drives, I'd just rely on the drive encryption and SANITIZE instructions of NVMe drives though, assuming that you want to protect the data in case it is removed from the system.

@MaartenBodewes the idea is to give the drives away to a partner for recycling, yet zero-trust policy requires that the third party cannot decrypt the sensible data. There is no need to keep the data, it can be deleted.

All good stuff; What if I then find your key (because of password complexity rules your manager wrote it on a Post-it)?

@PaulUszak imagine these SSDs are a server, a big cloud server maintained by a lot of people. The keys for encryption are saved in a safe place, which wont be avaialble to the third party, as they only get the SSDs with encrypted data on them. Are there known methods to still retrieve the data and decrypt it, having only the SSDs in hand?

The “35 times overwrite” is nonsense for SSDs. It was useful in the distant past because overwriting magnetic media could leave traces of magnetism behind.
SSDs don’t work like that. You cannot ever overwrite data; the new data will be written to new blocks, the old data remains in the same location. Same if you delete an old file and your SsD and OS support TRIM.
If TRIM is not properly supported, destroy the hard drive.  If it is supported then after deleting a file there is no mapping from logical to physical blocks. So you need to check with the manufacturer if reading physical blocks is possible. There is absolutely zero reason for this feature. If it is possible, dump the hard drive.
Last, many systems use full disk encryption with per-file encryption keys. If the file is removed from the directory, its encryption key is gone. For example, you need to break a 256 bit key for every single file on an iPhone.

How do you verify with 100% confidence that "If TRIM is not properly supported"

@PaulUszak if it’s not correctly supported that has anything between large and absolutely massive performance impact. All SSDs get less performance when full. TRIM recovers that performance when you delete files. So with a 1TB drive if you write 500GB it’s still fast. If you write 999GB it slows down. If you delete 499GB with TRIM it’s fast again, without TRIM it stays slow.

That effect is worst for TLC and QLC devices, especially with pseudo-SLC.

There is a the DoD 5220.22-M ECE standard which suggests for 3-pass, 7-pass and 35-pass delete are properly way to secure erase data from files, for most paranoid rewriting all allocated blocks with 0xAA (10101010), 0x55 (01010101), and then random (3-pass) shall be enought. I believe encrypting no matter how, is analogous to 1-pass, just a random one. One does not need to decrypt to still have some ability to recover data. For FDE (Full Disk Encryption) as long as all blocks are writte they are only written once, crypto defined by the algo hence analogous to random.
On bsd systems rm -P will offer some sort of compliance to this N-pass approach, for most Mac srm comes in the base system as of OSX, and srm can also be found on several Linux distros by default. In any case it can be isntalled as 3rd party package. Finally "secure erase Trash" on Mac OS gives this behavior as you would have deleting files using srm(1) on a Mac.
Several utilities can provide this, but srm(1) should always do.
For referece the standards mentioned are Peter Gutmann's 35 pass, Roy Pfitzner's 33-random-pass/7-random-pass  and the Pfitzner's simplified 3-pass.

DoD 5220.22-M is for hard drives, not SSDs. It's not a pertinent reference IMHO (clarification: when dealing with SSDs as in the question's title). Head misalignment that conceivably is an issue with some (old) hard disks and justify multiple passes do not matter with SSDs. OTOH the issue that writing to a logical sector might leave the physical data unmodified is very relevant to SSDs (and to a degree some modern hard disks, due to in-drive spare sectors management, and SMR technology).

The original question doent delimit the problem to a specific media type. And the question addresses the need for a wipe approach because the hypothetical receiver of the media "probably will try everything the market offers to get the data". SSD's drawback M-pass, are mostly related to wearing, to lifecycle and MTBF. The main concern here as I understand the question is confidentiality. Therefore I keep my answer. For a standard addressing only SSD, NIST 800-88 Clear and NIST 800-88 Purge however the first might left data recoverable the later depends o BLK ERASE existing on the disk.

@isacrofton could you describe me the challenges of keeping the data confidential on the SSD I am giving away to restore/recycle/repair, imagining the third party will do everything is possible to get the data? Assume I am the manufacturer of the SSD or the manufacturer isnt the attacker here. At that point, what has to be considered to make the data secure from the third party?
